# Parent child SSIS 2005 deployment with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2005

I have one master package and 29 child packages. I execute these 29 child packages from parent master package using an `Execute Package` task inside a for each loop container dynamically.

My concern is how can I deploy them in live? Should I create 29+1 database connection string with 30 configuration file because each child package executes a SQL Server stored procedure.

Any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: If they're all going to use the same database, why wouldn't you have them all use the same connection string in the same config file?

Comment: 29 child including master package will point to the same database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar challenge about a year ago. I've choosen to go for using a script task like it's described over [here](http://benefic.net/run-ssis-child-packages-with-script-task/). A SQL Server Agent job passes in the connectionstring and variables (i.e. source file paths) to the master package, the master package can use this technique to pass those along to the sub packages.

Comment: 29 child including master package will point to the same database